# System.Action<> defined multiple times when using Mono

Tags: c#, mono, action, monodevelop

I've been working on a winforms C# project in Visual Studio 2010 and have just started compiling it with Mono 2.10.8. Importing the project into Monodevelop 3.0.3.5 works great, and it compiles and runs without any trouble at all as long as the .NET runtime is used.

However, when I try to compile it with the Mono runtime, everything compiles except (two) references to System.Action and System.Func - I get error CS0433 that it is defined multiple times. I have references to System.dll, System.Drawing.dll, and System.Windows.Forms.dll which I'm using from the version 4.0 of the Mono libraries. I gather I'm getting a conflict between declarations in System.core - and somewhere else. Has anybody else had this problem? My entire project compiles and runs apart from perfectly apart from this!

**SOLVED**

It seems I was doing something rather dumb (though I'm going to blame the Monodevelop UI!) and that was causing the conflict. The projects were still set up to target the .NET framework 4 client profile. I didn't realise you could change them, as there no option to do so on the options for the solution, but there *is* on each individual project. I spent ages rooting through the included libraries and figured there was a conflict between v4.0 mscorlib.dll and v2.0 System.core.dll. When I replaced the v2.0 mscorelib.dll with the v4 it compiled fine.

I then discovered that simply changing the targetting to Mono / .NET 4 solves the problem. Oh well...

Comment: Is posible you referenced twice? This may occur if you have a Reference pointing to Mono, and a windows dll copied in Bin, I think...

Comment: Hmmm - when I added the references to Mono, it automatically makes a local copy of the windows dll in the bin direcotry. I tried turning off the make local copy option and it stops doing this - but same multiple reference error unfortunately.

Comment: I think this might be something to do with it [link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/620938/system-action-t1-t2-exists-in-3-5-system-core-dll-and-4-0-mscorlib-dll) - System.Action<T1,T2> is defined in both 3.5 system.core.dll and 4.0 mscorlib.dll

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that you have cleared out the bin /obj folder.

What do you use to compile mono (xbuild, monodevelop or a makefile?)?

Which compiler do you use dmcs?

These references (Func<> and Action<>) are a part of mscorlib. Mscorlib is added during link time.

Are you on an independant environment (vurtual machine) or mono and .NET are on the same PC?

Comment: Unfortunately still occurs with empty /obj folders. I'm using monodevelop with gmsc not inside an independent environment - mono and .NET are on the same machine (windows 7). Apart from the conflict the mono build works fine and runs as it should.

Comment: Edit - that should be dmcs, not gmcs.